# CKEditor css style broken

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I have just download ckEditor and have a display problem. As my page defined styles for body, p...and now these style affects to ckEditor css because it defined css tag body, too..and this make ckEditor style broke

So, what should I do to separate these css to display ckEditor correctly on my page?

One more question, I defined a css as below for my table which set classname is "standardTable01"

```
.standardTable01 {
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #428bca;
  width: 500px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.standardTable01 thead tr:first-child {
  background: #428bca;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
}

.standardTable01 th {font-weight: bold;}
.standardTable01 th:first-child, td:first-child {padding: 0 15px 0 20px;}

.standardTable01 thead tr:last-child th {border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;}

.standardTable01 tbody tr:hover {background-color: #f0fbff; opacity:0.6}
.standardTable01 tbody tr:last-child td {border: none;}
.standardTable01 tbody td {border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;}

.standardTable01 td:last-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

and this defined affects to ckEditor as well. I don't know why was that because ckEditor did not set the table classname the same to mine "standardTable01"...

Thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the CSS file you accidentally used this:

```
.standardTable01 th:first-child, td:first-child {...}
```

Before `td:first-child` you did not add `.standardTable01`

Regarding the first question, you'd need to post an example of a style that "conflicts" with CKEditor.

Comment: When I create new table but does not set a classname="standardTable01" that table is not totally applied these css. But CKEditor is